# How to get collection from JSON array

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of JSON in ajax response in javascript.

```
[{"id":1,"text":"apple"},{"id":2,"text":"mango"},{"id":3,"text":"banana"}]
```

I want to extract a comma separated list of `ids` like `"1, 2, 3"` from this JSON response. How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? why is it not working? are you getting any errors, etc...

Comment: I don't have any idea to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you parse the JSON (if you didn't do that already):

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"text":"apple"},{"id":2,"text":"mango"},{"id":3,"text":"banana"}]');
```

Then you loop the array to extract the id on each object. You can use the `map` method of arrays to loop and add the ids to a new array in one go:

```
var ids = arr.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});
alert(ids.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json is stored as a string `jsonstr` in your js code:

```js
/*parse the JSON to a JS object*/
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstr); 
var ids = [];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

   //loop over the array and if the id is defined add it
   if(typeof data[i].id !== "undefined"){
       ids.push(data[i].id);
   }
}
```

Comment: @bfavaretto good question.  Doesn't like comments at all apparently

Comment: @bfavaretto go for it.  I just tried about 5 different things, any combination with comments, even if I use /**/ on its own line, breaks the code that comes after.

Comment: I just posted a question on meta about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171669/syntax-highlighter-failing-for-specific-code-block

Comment: @bfavaretto and it got fixed quickly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "apple"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "mango"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "banana"
}];
var ar = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[i].id);
}

alert(ar.join(','))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3w5S/1/

Comment: Thats not a JSON string you're defining, its a javascript object.

Comment: @ben336:  correct me if i am wrong, original poster has already said he has "an array of JSON" and i  intrepreted it as being parsed JSON in array form already

Comment: But he's got all his properties double quoted.  Looks much more like a JSON string.  Its always possible he's confused, but he's saying that he has JSON, and he's formatted it like its JSON so I don't think there's much reason to think its not JSON

Answer (score -1):

About this:

```
x = [{"id":1,"text":"apple"},{"id":2,"text":"mango"},{"id":3,"text":"banana"}];
str = "";
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  str += x[i].id.toString() + ',';
}
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Not defining variables with "var". Assuming an "id" exists. Calling toString unnecessarily when it is already being concentrated around two strings. If any one "id" is undefined it won't have a toString method and this snippet will error. Original poster said they wanted it concentrated by a comma plus a space. I see no space. Also using an overly complicated suspicious-looking substring approach to trim off the last character when a simple array and join would do the trick. And finally assuming the response is already an array when the Original Poster mentioned JSON which needs to be parsed.